# Resize superview and all superview's siblings using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to manage the views on my screen so that all views are updated in accordance with a text view that is growing depending on the text that is entered.

On my controller's view i have two subviews. Let's call them view1 and view2. View1 has a uitextview subview that is growing and shrinking depending on the text that is entered.

The issue I'm having is that view1 and view2 don't to grow and shrink whilst typing. The constraint constant for vertical spacing from the bottom on the textView has been set to 10px from it's superview. Vertical spacing between view1 and view2 is set to 0. Here is a visual representation of the view:

```
 ---------------------
|                     |
|  -----------------  |
| |   UITextView    | |
|  -----------------  |
|        view1        |
 ---------------------
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|        view2        |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
 ---------------------
```

The result I'm getting whilst I add text to the textView is:

```
 ---------------------
|                     |
|  -----------------  |
| |   UITextView    | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
 ---------------------
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|        view2        |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
 ---------------------
```

But the desired behavior would be something along the lines of:

```
 ---------------------
|                     |
|  -----------------  |
| |   UITextView    | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
|  -----------------  |
|        view1        |
 ---------------------
|                     |
|                     |
|        view2        |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
 ---------------------
```

The strange thing is, once I've added the text and pressed submit (not added to diagram for simplicity), view1 grows to the correct size, as does view2, but not whilst typing.

Do I need to explicitly call setNeedsUpdateConstraints or updateConstraintsIfNeeded? If so, where? I have tried calling it from the text view delegate textViewDidChange: but nothing has helped.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't need to update the constraints as they probably aren't changing. The size of the objects are, but not the constraint objects. Try calling setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded when the contents of the view change.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the response. Nope, I've tried calling [self.view setNeedsLayout] and [self.view layoutIfNeeded] from the textViewDidChange callback but it doesn't seem to work. That's what i was thinking too. The constraints shouldn't change but rather the views. The constraint between the textview and view1 should "push" it down, whilst the constraint between view1 and view2 should shrink the size of view2..

Comment: Could it be that the UITextView is not actually growing? UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so the typing is probably not causing the frame of the UITextView to need to be changed. It's probably just updating the contentSize and internal views representing that text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out.

For anyone reading this having the same issue, the way I did it was to write my own subclass of UITextView giving it a height constraint and a few delegate methods.

When changing the height of the text view, simply fire the delegate method (e.g. textViewDidChangeHeight:). Then, in the delegate call back implementation, I just called sizeToFit on the view.